# How to remove all words from a string except the last one with PHP?

Tags: php

How can I remove all words from a string except the last one with PHP?

For example the string `"Organic Black Olives"` would become `"Olives"`.

Comment: explode as space and get the last index value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$str = "Organic Black Olives";
// get words list
$words = explode(' ', $str);
// get last word
$last_word = $words[count($words)-1];

echo $last_word;
```